# User space buffer and Kernel buffer

Tags: c, linux, buffer

I am recently studying file system in linux. I learned that when we call fopen(), the library call will call malloc() to allocate space for the FILE structure, and inside this FILE structure there will be a buffer for I/0. But later on I found that the write system call actually writes the data to the kernel buffer, So what's the difference between these two buffers?

Comment: Don't mind, you need to have a book to read first.

Comment: I do have a book, it's advanced UNIX programming. Just want to get things straight

Answer (score 15):

You have to understand two things: `fwrite()` is a standard library's routine operating on `FILE` structure, but `write()` is a system call. I bet `fwrite()` uses `write()` internally. Nothing keeps `fwrite()` from providing user space IO-buffering until it is ready to pass your data on to the `write()` syscall.

`write()` syscall in it's turn goes straight to the kernel and says: "Hey kernel, I've got this user space buffer here. Will you write this one to the storage for me?".  And here it's up to the kernel what to do next: it will either go directly to storage to write the data, or, most likely, copy the data to kernel buffer, until it decides it's time to modify storage data.

Turning back to your question. Any kind of buffering is done to accumulate data in order to postpone turning to more expensive operations: standard library may consider invoking syscall on every `len`-byte expensive, kernel considers going to hard disk on every syscall expensive and so on.

You might want to read this to see how far buffering goes https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2015/10/25/reading-and-writing-are-less-symmetric-than-you-probably-think/

Comment: So library function has its own buffer or the buffer is in the FILE structure?

Comment: It's in the `FILE` structure, I guess. Look, library buffers IO  on a per-file basis. In order to do its per-file work it gives application some opaque `FILE *` file handle, so that when you turn to library's routine you pass that handle in. This handle tell everything to the routine the latter has to know to do it's job (buffering included).

Answer (score 1):

The `FILE` structure holds the **meta** data about the opened file (mode, stream position, etc). It is part of the C Standard I/O interface.
The buffer allocated as part of `FILE` takes only a limited amount of data (e.g. when the stream is buffered). It is deallocated upon `fclose()`. You may even provide your own user space stdio buffer with `setvbuf()`.

The kernel buffer receives the **file contents** written by `write()`, whenever the stream is flushed or the associated file descriptor is closed.

Comment: Does that mean that if the stream is buffered, data is first written to user space buffer then to kernel space buffer? But what if the stream is not buffered, for example, the stderr, does it mean that the output go straightly to the error message and does not even get stored in kernel cache?

Comment: @lplouis Yes, if the stream is buffered, it goes to the `FILE` buffer first. That's the whole point: avoiding **expensive** system calls for only a handful of bytes. If it is unbuffered, any operation goes directly to a read() or write(). The latter one you usually want for diagnostic messages: you want to be informed as soon as something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The FILE structure holds the information about the opened file.[this defines the FILE struct members](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/libio.h;h=3cf1712ea98d3c253f418feb1ef881c4a44649d5;hb=HEAD#l245). But in kernel level a file has been accessed by [inode](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-unixlinux-filesystem-inodes.html), [buffer cache](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/buffer-cache.html).

Data is getting read/write to disk from user space through buffer cache using method [copy_to_user](https://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/kernel-api/re256.html) and [copy_from_user](https://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/kernel-api/re257.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is a very big difference between the two buffers, one is **`kernel`** buffer and the other is the **`user`** buffer. So, what basically happens when you do a I/O is that the buffer from the user space is copied into a buffer in the kernel space. The function `copy_from_user()` does this task.

Now the question which arises is why do we need two buffers, when the kernel has access into the user space? The reason is that the kernel does not want to read the user buffer directly because both the kernel and the user space has different address spaces and so a valid address in user space might not be a valid address in kernel.

In kernel if a non-valid address is accessed then the system will panic immediately, so the function `copy_from_user` does the task of mapping the user space address and the kernel space address and checks if the address is accessible or not. If not then it simply returns `EFAULT` (bad address).